# How to get updated value from a database and show it on the page using ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, updates

I have a rails form that imports remotely some products from a google spreadsheet. While doing so, it updates company that makes those products by setting its company.import_status to "started", when the importing starts, and "finish", once it's done.

I have a page that shows company.import_status, and I try to update it so I can see when an import starts and when it's finished. My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  <% @companies.each do |company| %>
    setInterval(function(company){
      $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'import',
        dataType : 'html',
        success : function(company){
          $("#company_<%=company.id%>").html("<%= escape_javascript(Company.where(id: company.id).first.import_status) %>");
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert('Error!');
        }
      });

    }, 1000);
  <% end %>
});
```

For some reason, the field doesn't get updated. It starts off as "started" and just stays that way. What can I change to fix this? If I try getting it through console, it gives me the correct value.

**Update:**

this is my import method

```
def import 
  @companies = Company.find(params[:company].values.map{ |c| c[:id] }.compact)
  @companies.each do |company| company.key = params[:company].values.select {|c| c[:id] == company.id.to_s}.first[:file] if !company.import_in_progress? company.import_start 
 end 
 end
 respond_to do |format| 
     format.html { redirect_to admin_import_index_path } 
     format.js 
 end 
end
```

Comment: where are you updating that field(I mean the code ) please add it here

Comment: form submission does that.

Comment: please add this to your question so that it will be clear

Comment: `def import`
   `@companies = Company.find(params[:company].values.map{ |c| c[:id] }.compact)`
    `@companies.each do |company|`
      `company.key = params[:company].values.select {|c| c[:id] == company.id.to_s}.first[:file]`
      `if !company.import_in_progress?`
        `company.import_start`
      `end`
    `end`
    `respond_to do |format|`
     ` format.html { redirect_to admin_import_index_path }`
     ` format.js`
   ` end`
  end 
`
This is what the form submit does.

Comment: As per your code you are not updating your import_status field right

Comment: I am, because when I check through console it is updated.

Comment: how you are retrieving the updated value in your console

Comment: `Company.find(company.id).reload.import_status`

Comment: then try to use the same in your ajax success function `$("#company_<%=company.id%>").html("<%= escape_javascript(Company.where(id: company.id).reload.first.import_status) %>");`

Comment: I have tried this:
`$("#company_<%=company.id%>").html("<%= escape_javascript(Company.find(company.id).reload.import_status) %>");`
as @Milind suggested, but I still get "started" over and over again..

Comment: And your way with `where` doesn't to the trick either :/

Comment: please post your form submission code here

Comment: `def import`

    `@companies = Company.find(params[:company].values.map{ |c| c[:id] }.compact)`

    `@companies.each do |company|`

      `company.key = params[:company].values.select {|c| c[:id] == company.id.to_s}.first[:file]`

      `if !company.import_in_progress?`

        `company.import_start`

     ` end`

   ` end`

    `respond_to do |format|`

      `format.html { redirect_to admin_import_index_path }`

      `format.js`

   ` end`

 ` end`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to format this..

Comment: once try like this `$("#company_<%=company.id%>").html("<%= escape_javascript(company.reload.import_status) %>");`

Comment: @ivanacorovic please edit your question using the link under tags and add an "Update" title to update instead of posting code into comments!

Comment: I wish.. started forever :(

Comment: Looks like whatever I put in `success:`, it always gives me the same output. I tried some random numbers and stuff, if they're set outside the `success` part, they'll always be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was happening is that ruby code got compiled and kind of hardcoded first, so when javascipt took place, whatever was initially set in ruby stayed that way. That-s why I kept getting "started". This is what approach I used instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function() {
    $.get("/companies.json", function(data){
      $.each(data, function(index, c) {
        var field = "#company" + "_" + c["id"];
          $(field).html(c["import_status"]);
          console.log(field);
       });
    });
  }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to reload the records to get latest updated ones..use [reload](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/reload).i Used it to get the `confirmation_token` which was somehow giving me the old one...so i used it to get the latest data from the db..

```
User.find(current_user.id).reload
```

..HOPE IT HELPS