# Get live updated data with ajax in a react component

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs

**Story:**

User clicks "add", it sets a value in the database to `true`. Clicks "remove", updates same column to `false` in the database:

```
def add
  u = User.find(1)
  u.foo = true
  u.save
  u.reload
  head :ok
end

def remove
  u = User.find(1)
  u.foo = false
  u.save
  u.reload
  head :ok
end
```

**React button component:**

```
...

_add(){
  $.ajax({
    url: ''url-to-the-controller-action-(add),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("DB is set to: " this.props.uid)
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("not added")
    }
  });
},

_remove(){
  $.ajax({
    url: ''url-to-the-controller-action-(remove),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("DB is set to: " this.props.uid) 
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("not removed")
    }
  });
},

render(){
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={this._add}>add</button>
      <button onClick={this._remove}>remove</button>
    </div>
  )
}

...
```

My button receives props from another component:

**Foo component**

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return{
    uid: this.props.data,

  }
}
```

**Foo's render:**

```
<Button uid={this.state.uid} />
```

I am sure I can achieve this without the need for flux/redux as that would be an over kill for this tiny component. [I have looked into this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583070/how-to-get-updated-value-from-a-database-and-show-it-on-the-page-using-ajax) but not sure how to use it.

The app works but I have to refresh the page to see the changes.

Or, Rails 5 is my best option with action cable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On success, you need to inform **Foo** component than **uid** has changed.

In **Foo** component:

```
onChange: (uid) ->
   this.setState({uid: uid})

render: ->
  <Button uid={this.state.uid} onChange={this.onChange}/>
```

In **Button** component:

```
_add(){
  $.ajax({
    url: ''url-to-the-controller-action-(add),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
     this.props.onChange(data["uid"])
     console.log("DB is set to:", data["uid"])
    },
    error: function (data) {
       console.log("not added")
    }
  });
},
```

In your action:

```
def add
  ...
  render json: { uid: u.foo }
end
```

On why you need refresh here:

When you make your ajax call, data are updated in database. But on your success callback, you need to update your view with new data. When you log **this.props.uid**, you log old data in memory, and when you hit refresh, data are replaced by fresh data from database.

In **jQuery** for example, you need to replace your element in DOM with fresh data passed in success callback. In **ReactJS**, you need to update the state to re-render the component.

Here, your component **Button** is a child of **Foo**, and receive **uid** like props. So you need to inform your parent component than **uid** has changed to update state, and re-render itself, and his childs.

Comment: Ok. Ill have a go later today. I'll report back. Thanks